# Angular 5 - Send Errors from Child Template Component to Parent through ngModel

Tags: angular, error-handling, angular5, angular2-template

Here is my stackblitz demo showing the issue clearly, I hope:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-communication-1-75lwpg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

The issue is that my child sin number component has the **required validator** and it works correctly LOCALLY, this can be demonstrated by the *ngIf statement that shows "ERROR" if nothing of length 5 was typed, but the parent cannot access that error! How do I overcome this issue?

One solution I have come up with is to use the validate(c: FormControl) using NG_VALIDATORS, I commented it out in the demo (feel free to uncomment), but I would rather have a way to use the child component template, so I don't have to write required in the parent html.

In the example, sinNumber1 and sinNumber2 are exactly the same except that sinNumber2 has the required validator tag in the parent! I want sinNumber1 to behave like sinNumber2 in showing the error.

.
 .

In my parent component I have the following code and custom component:

```
<b> Notice that sinNumber2 errors works but sinNumber1 does not </b> <br>
<b> I want sinNumber1 to work similarly to sinNumber2 but using the template of the child component </b> <br>

<br>



User | json {{ user | json }} <br> <br>


<form #personalDetailsForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  personalDetailsForm?.controls?.sinNumber : {{ personalDetailsForm?.controls?.sinNumber1?.errors  | json }} <br>
  personalDetailsForm?.controls?.sinNumber2 : {{ personalDetailsForm?.controls?.sinNumber2?.errors  | json }} <br>
------------------------------------------------------ <br>
SinNumber1:
       <app-sin-number
          id="sinNumber1"
          name="sinNumber1"
          [(ngModel)]="user.sinNumber1"
          #sinNumberCtrl1="ngModel"
        > </app-sin-number>
sinNumberCtrl?.errors: {{ sinNumberCtrl1?.errors | json }} <b>--I should not see null!</b> <br>  

------------------------------------------------------ <br>
SinNumber2 (notice the <b>required</b> tag):
        <app-sin-number
          id="sinNumber2"
          name="sinNumber2"
          [(ngModel)]="user.sinNumber2"
          #sinNumberCtrl2="ngModel"
          required
        > 
        </app-sin-number>
sinNumberCtrl2?.errors:  {{ sinNumberCtrl2?.errors | json }}<b>--I should see this error!</b> <br> 

</form>
------------------------------------------------------ <br>
```

Parent Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

    public doNotGetHere: Boolean = false;

    @ViewChild('personalDetailsForm') personalDetailsForm: NgForm;
    public user: User = new User();
    onSubmit() { 
        if (this.personalDetailsForm.valid) {
          // I do not want to get here if I entered nothing in the sin-number input box!
        }
    }
}

export class User {
  sinNumber1: any = '';
  sinNumber2: any = '';
}
```

Sin Number Html:

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div>
      <div>
          <div class="form-field">
              <div class="form-label-group">
                  <input id="sinNumber"
                        name="sinNumber"

                        #sinNumberCtrl="ngModel"
                        [(ngModel)]="value" 

                        type="text"
                        minlength="5"
                        maxlength="5"

                        required />
              </div>

          </div>
          <div class="error-message" *ngIf="sinNumberCtrl.invalid && sinNumberCtrl.touched ">
             ERROR
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SinNumberComponent.ts:

```
import {  HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, forwardRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl, Validators, NgForm, FormGroupDirective, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

const noop = () => {};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sin-number',
  templateUrl: './sin-number.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sin-number.component.css'],
    providers: [
    FormGroupDirective,
      { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => SinNumberComponent), multi: true },
    //  { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => SinNumberComponent), multi: true }
    ],
})
export class SinNumberComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {


    @ViewChild('sinNumberCtrl') sinNumberCtrl: NgForm; // could this work?
    private form: FormGroupDirective; // could this work?

    constructor() {    }

    ngOnInit() {    }

    // The internal data model
    private innerValue: any = '';

    // Placeholders for the callbacks which are later provided
    // by the Control Value Accessor
    private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
    private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;
    propagateChange: any = () => {};
    validateFn: any = () => {};

    // get accessor
    get value(): any {
        return this.innerValue;
    }

    // set accessor including call the onchange callback
    set value(v: any) {
        if (v !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = v;
            this.onChangeCallback(v);
        }
    }

    // From ControlValueAccessor interface
    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = value;
        }
    }

    // From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    // From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }

    // This way works but what if I only want to use the sin-number.component.html code?
  //  validate(c: FormControl) {
  //    return Validators.required(c);
 ///   }
}
```

Comment: I am starting to think there is no template-driven solution. If you want to do template driven validators then they have to be added locally in the component and in the parent like sinNumber2 in my example.

Otherwise you can just use reactive validators.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is expose a public method in Child Component validateFormFields() which will validate the form controls in child component and return the validation result.

You can call the child component validateFormFields()  in parent component using @ViewChild(SinNumberComponent) sinnumcomp: SinNumberComponent;

const result = this.sinnumcomp.validateFormFields();

Comment: Thanks that could work but I was hoping for a solution much like using NG_VALIDATORS where the component itself would propagate the required error for the parent to see.

Answer (score 0):

SinNumberCtrl2 has a errors inside control._errors

```
<app-sin-number
          id="sinNumber2"
          name="sinNumber2"
          [(ngModel)]="user.sinNumber2"
          #sinNumberCtrl2="ngModel"
          required
        > 
        </app-sin-number>
sinNumberCtrl2?.errors:  {{ sinNumberCtrl2?.control._errors | json }}
```

I have Edited Your Code Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-communication-1-bszcfv

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear but yeah I know it does, because I added the **required** tag for it! I am saying that sinNumber1 I see nothing when I ideally I should see {"required": true} like sinNumber2

Comment: if you want to see then you have to add required tag to sinNumber1 also

Comment: But required attribute is present in <input> inside sin-number.component.html

Comment: since he using controlvalueaccessor if you remove  <!-- id="sinNumber1"
          name="sinNumber1"
          [(ngModel)]="user.sinNumber1"
          #sinNumberCtrl1="ngModel"
          required --> these code form  app-sin-number component he would not get any error object

Comment: @Dil if you remove required from sinNumber2  and check you wil get same result

Comment: @Chellappan that's not what I want haha! I want sinNumber1 to show the required error! 

I am starting to think there is no template-driven solution. Except to add the validators in the parent.